# Regular Expression, perl matching numbers before specific text

Tags: regex, perl

Please clarify I have bunch of badly formated text files from where I have to take data.
The text example:

```
my $content = "Abracadabra 10 anbracadabra 20 blah \n blah 1220 blah \nblah IMPORTANT blah blah 10 abracadabra 10"
```

I need to get 1220. Ie closest numbers sequence to "IMPORTANT" from left to right. 
The problem is that the sequence can have any amount of digits. 
I made an expression which works but I have to tell how many digits there exactly:

```
my ($number) = $content=~m/.*(\d\d\d\d).*?IMPORTANT/gs
```

Anything like (\d+) gives me obviously only last digit..

If possible shed some explanation not bare code, please. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\b(\d+)\D*?IMPORTANT
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gK1eO7/1)

- match 1 or more digits in a capture group using word boundary i.e. `\b(\d+)`
- followed by 0 or more non-digits `\D*?` (non-greedy)
- followed by literal text `IMPORTANT`

For your example it gives `1220` in captured group.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it works, in my example my pattern with \d+ also works... I guess I was too-smart*a** and  made a wrong example :-(
I have made a better one on regex101... I wish the result be >29< and not >2011< 
[link to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gK1eO7/1)

Comment: But your link is same as my demo link.

Comment: Sorry haste makes waste... 
[link](https://regex101.com/r/sQ6sQ4/1)
Looks like it works now? 
Thanks for responding so fast Anubhava, its 3AM now and I was loosing all hopes for good sleep, as my wake up at 6-30...

Comment: Its 4 AM here as well :). Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.